# Can I create completions file for rlwrap?

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, rlwrap

I use the following script to start the toplevel:

```sh
breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''\\"
exec rlwrap --remember -c -b "$breakchars"  -f "$HOME"/.ml_completions -S '> ' ocaml -init ~/.ocamlinit "$@"
```

Then how can I build the .ml_completions file so that I can auto-complete input in the toplevel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to create a completion file for rlwrap, but you can use utop as an alternative:

https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop

It supports line editing, context-sensitive completion and syntax highlighting in the toplevel.